# How do you solve $(D^2+1)y = \ln|\cos(x)|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuch on this question:

$$(D^2+1)y = \ln|\cos x|  $$

where $D^2$ denotes the differential operator $d^2y/dx^2$

I suppose that I will begin with these lines:

For cos(x) function use $(D^2+1)$

$$(D^2+1)^2y = 0$$
$$(D^4+2D^2+1)y = 0$$

How can I continue if it is correct beginning. How can I solve this question?

Comment: $(D^4+2D^2+1)y = 0$You can't do this since cosine function is inside the ln function..Do you know variation of parameters method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the operator method the way you did since the cosine function is inside an ln function. So we don't have:
$$(D^2+1)^2y=0$$

Solve the homogeneous equation first
$$y''+y=0$$
$$\implies r^2+1=0 \implies r=\pm i$$
The solution to the homogeneous equation is:
$$y_h=A\cos x +B \sin x$$
For the particular solution, you can use [variation of parameter method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters).

The particular solution is given by the following formula:
$$y_p=A(x)\cos x + B(x) \sin x$$
Where the coefficients are:
$$\pmatrix {\cos x & \sin x \\ -\sin x & \cos x }\pmatrix {A'(x) \\ B'(x)}=\pmatrix {0 \\\ln (\cos x)}$$
$$\pmatrix {A'(x) \\ B'(x)}=\pmatrix {\cos x & -\sin x \\ \sin x & \cos x }\pmatrix {0 \\\ln (\cos x)}$$
You evaluate these two integrals:
$$A(x)=-\int \sin x \ln (\cos x) dx$$
$$A(x)=\int  \ln (\cos x) d\cos x$$
$$A(x)=\cos  x \ln (\cos x) -\cos x $$
And:
$$B(x)=\int \cos x \ln (\cos x) dx$$
This integral can easily be integrated by part.